# SQL Server Alter Table with Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

cant find this question anywhere... I have this statement:

```
select State=(CASE Discount
WHEN 0 THEN sum((Price * Quantity) * (1 + Discount)) 
ELSE sum((Price * Quantity) * (Discount)) end)
from Table1 where OrderID is not null group by Price, OrderID, Discount 
order by  OrderID
```

what this is doing is calculating a total based upon whether there is a number in the discount column, the reason being if its 0, then I add 1 to prevent the total being set to 0 and the number will just times by itself. the other statement calculates the remainder that have a percentage. Now this statements works perfect, however I cant work out the order/syntax for the Alter table or Update statements, any help would be great, cheers :) and here is what I have so far:

```
Alter table Table1 add Total As 
(CASE Discount
WHEN 0 THEN sum((Price * Quantity) * (1 + Discount)) 
ELSE sum((Price * Quantity) * (Discount)) end)
from Table1 where OrderID is not null group by Price, OrderID, Discount     
order by OrderID
```

^^ above doesn't like the word 'FROM'

```
update Table1 Total = CASE Discount
WHEN 0 THEN sum((Price * Quantity) * (1 + Discount)) 
ELSE sum(Price * Quantity) * (Discount)) end
```

^^ above gives this error 
Msg 157, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Comment: You can't use a subquery in a computed column. If you feel like it is a definition you will need to reused then your best option would be to create a view.

Comment: so that's what to 2 above errors mean then?

plus if I create a view can I add a procedure to update the view so the total table is updated automatically? thanks for the help

Comment: You don't need to populate a view, it is essentially just a saved query, so when you reference the view you will always get up to date results.

Comment: solved it using JavaScript, will post when it lets me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
Create view ExtenededPriceView as:
select OrderID, EquipmentID, ExtendedPrice = 
(Case
WHEN 
(Discount = 0) THEN sum((UnitPrice * Quantity))
ELSE 
sum((1 - Discount) * UnitPrice) * Quantity END)
from Table1  where OrderID is not null 
group by Discount, Quantity, EquipmentID, OrderID
```

then a procedure to call:

```
create procedure UpdateExtendedPrice as
update Table1 set Table1.ExtendedPrice = 
ExtenededPriceView.ExtendedPrice
from Table1 inner join ExtenededPriceView on    
Table1.EquipmentID = ExtenededPriceView.EquipmentID
where ExtenededPriceView.EquipmentID =
(select TOP 1 EquipmentID from ExtenededPriceView order by EquipmentID desc)
```

Comment: `Case WHEN (Discount = 0) THEN sum((UnitPrice * Quantity) * (1 + Discount)` - This makes no sense. If your `CASE` expression is checking to see if Discount is 0, then why bother multiplying by 1 + Discount? Just don't do any multiplying at all for that particular condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why you're going out of your way to create a view, and then a procedure, just to update a column. If you're going to repeatedly call this throughout your code, then it might make some sense, depending on the situation. But if you're only going to refer to this in one spot in your code, well, just use this UPDATE.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/486a9/2

```
--Setup
CREATE TABLE Table1(
    ID INT,
    Discount FLOAT,
    Price FLOAT,
    Quantity INT,
    Total FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, Discount, Price, Quantity) VALUES (1, 0, 5, 5), (2, (1 - .15), 4.5, 3);

--Doing work.
UPDATE t SET Total = [State]
FROM Table1 t, (select ID, [State]=(CASE Discount
WHEN 0 THEN sum(Price * Quantity) 
ELSE sum(Price * Quantity * Discount) end)
from Table1 GROUP BY ID, Discount, Price) a
WHERE t.ID = a.ID;

--See the results.
SELECT * FROM Table1;
```

This is essentially how the database will treat what you've written, except I'm not creating any long-term database objects and simplifying it all into one query. I cleaned up your SELECT a bit (a lot less parenthesis now). I'm also assuming that your ID column is unique. And if ID is unique, I don't think you need to GROUP on Price.

However, a better solution, I think, would be to calculate Total either on INSERT of this data or on the fly when the data is needed.